# How to change canvas size in OpenGL? glClearColor is only painting a small box

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

When I run the following open gl command, it only paints the bottom left part of the ipad screen red.

glClearColor(255.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

[image]

How do I make it so the whole screen gets painted red?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't set the framebuffer to the correct size. If you are on an iPhone 4, the most common mistake is to use the reported view dimensions, which are the same as for the earlier models, even though the iPhone 4 has twice the resolution.

Here's how I do it in my app (Important Caveat: this is all black-magic to me, so take it with a grain of salt, and please don't ask me to explain it):

```
- (BOOL)resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer *)layer {
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:layer];
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &vWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &vHeight);

    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, vWidth, vHeight);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @joe - Marcelo's code is a standard implementation of the generation of a framebuffer at the same size as the backing layer for a view.  If your code differs from this, that could be a source of your problems.  If it's the same, make sure that the UIView which hosts your OpenGL ES content is being properly resized to fit the entire display before the framebuffer is being created.

Comment: His code will not even compile because vWidth and vHeight are not defined.

Comment: @joe: Sorry, it was a snippet of code from a larger app (obviously). vWidth and vHeight are simply variables declared in the class.

Comment: @joe - Yes, those are probably defined as `GLint vWidth; GLint vHeight;` elsewhere.  You should have something similar in your own code for setting up the backing width and height, especially if you're basing it on one of Apple's OpenGL ES templates.

Answer (score 1):

Does [`glViewport()`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glViewport.xml) not work?

Comment: glViewport changes the size of the images but not what gets colored in with glClearColor.

Answer (score 0):

> I am on an iPad using example code made for the iPhone

Is it possible that the window size in the code is hard coded to the smaller iPhone screen dimensions?

**Edit:**
This [idevgames forum post](http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-7899.html) looks like the same xcode issue (not OpenGL), caused by:

1. Starting with an iPhone project in xcode
2. Incorrect settings in the .xib file

Two solutions, neither tested by me are:
1)

> UIWindow resizing can be achieved with manual conversion of .xib files to iPad version using Interface Builder.
>   This is mentioned in [iOS 4.0 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-4_0/) in Known Issues->Xcode section.
>   This do the trick for me.

2)

> Save yourself a lot of trouble, just create a new iPad OGLES app in xcode, everything will already be setup and working for you, drag your files in from your old xcode project into your new one, update the xib with the correct app delate and your done. I had to start a whole new project today and do this just to get the MF#*!!FS#$**! code signing to work.