# Using iPhone 5 full screen for non retina game

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, retina-display, iphone-5

I would like to update my non retina game to use the wide screen in the iPhone 5, is it possible to use a 568x320 sized OpenGL window?

Comment: this might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715689/how-to-change-canvas-size-in-opengl-glclearcolor-is-only-painting-a-small-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now compiled and got my game working at 568x320, all I had to do is include the Default-568h@2x file and do this in createFrameBuffer

```
[self setFrame:rect];
[self setBounds:rect];
[self.layer setFrame:rect];
[self.layer setBounds:rect];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But your graphics will not show as sharp as it could be.

I suggest you to make `@2x` version of all your graphics.

Comment: "I suggest you to make `@2x` version of all your graphics." Assuming they've not targeted retina devices already (iPhone 4 onwards). The taller screen on iPhone 5 does not warrant `@2x` graphics more than a iPhone 4.

Comment: Making higher res graphics is not a possibility.  I simply want to extend the game play area to include the extra screen real estate the iPhone 5 provides.  So how do I do this, is it simply a matter of including the special sized splash screen and the game will then use the widescreen of the iphone 5?